# Kubernetes services not appearing in Jaeger UI

Tags: kubernetes, istio, jaeger, distributed-tracing

Is there a way to get Kubernetes services to register in Jaeger?

I have Jaeger v1.37.0 installed using helm. But services don't seem to get registered with it.

I've gone through some documentation which suggest that the Zipkin port needs to be enabled, which I have implemented

```
collector:
  service:
    zipkin:
      port: 9411
```

Istio has also been configured to use the Zipkin address.

```
global:
  tracer:
    zipkin:
      address: "jaeger-collector.monitor.svc.cluster.local:9411"
```

But in the Jaeger UI, none of my services appear to be registering, apart from the jaeger-query service.

Is there someother configuration that needs to be put in place to get these services to register?

Comment: I'm stuck with the exact same problem as well. 
Can't seem to get services to appear in the Jaeger UI.